# presto + Query exceeded distributed user memory limit of XXGB

Tags: linux, presto

we have presto cluster around 100 presto workers machines and of course one coordinator

all presto are installed on Linux RHEL 7.9 version

sometimes we get exceptions on presto UI , and exception is like this:

```
io.prestosql.ExceededMemoryLimitException: Query exceeded distributed user memory limit of 600GB
    at io.prestosql.ExceededMemoryLimitException.exceededGlobalUserLimit(ExceededMemoryLimitException.java:29)
    at io.prestosql.memory.ClusterMemoryManager.process(ClusterMemoryManager.java:234)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryManager.enforceMemoryLimits(SqlQueryManager.java:291)
    at io.prestosql.execution.SqlQueryManager.lambda$start$0(SqlQueryManager.java:104)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

so exception actually talks about - `Query exceeded distributed user memory limit of 600GB`

but not clearly why presto complain about value - 600GB , and how comes presto cluster find this value - 600GB and according to what configuration?

for example our config files are looks like the following

```
coordinator=false
http-server.http.port=4545
discovery.uri=http://coordinator:4545
task.max-worker-threads=24
#experimental.internal-communication.binary-transport-enabled=true
query.max-memory-per-node=15GB
query.max-total-memory-per-node=35GB
node-scheduler.max-splits-per-node=200
node-scheduler.max-pending-splits-per-task=20

 more jvm.config
 #
-server
-Xmx32G
-XX:+UseG1GC
```

so we not understand why presto complain about **600GB?** and how presto calculate this value the value **600GB**